# Solvent choice in imine formation from quercetin and poly(allylamine)

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, solvents

I am trying to react quercetin and poly(allylamine) to form imine on the repeating units. Poly(allylamine) is dissolved in water. The problem is the choice of solvent. Poly(allylamine) is soluble in water, lower alcohols, formamide, and ethylene glycol. Quercetin is insoluble in water, and soluble in DMF and DMSO. Quercetin also dissolves in lower alcohols, but very small amounts (approximately 2 mg in 1 mL). What solvent can I choose? Should I try reaction in heterogeneous phase? Or, it is known that DMF is miscible with methanol or ethanol, so should I try cosolvent of these?

Comment: These papers look like they may be useful, but I can only read the abstracts https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00955714   https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acsaem.0c02178

Comment: DMF is fully miscible with MeOH and EtOH, I would try co-solvents

Comment: @Waylander Thank you for advice. I would try it.